# How is the unit of measure "equivalent" abbreviated?

Tags: units

I usually use "eq" but I have been told to use "equiv." in order to avoid confusion with "equation". Is there a reference I can check?

Comment: Santiago's answer is authoritative but if you want to invent your own abbreviation that is (i) shorter than `equiv` and (ii) avoids ambiguity with `equation`, I suggest "eqv".

Comment: Yes, and to @CurtF.' comment - whatever you choose to do - be consistent.

Answer (score 8):

The first place to check would be standards that are used frequently globally, such as [CAS](https://www.cas.org/cas-home). According to the American Chemical Society page [CAS Standard Abbreviations & Acronyms](https://www.cas.org/content/cas-standard-abbreviations), the abbreviation for the unit of measurement 'equivalent' is `equiv`, while that of the adjective 'equivalent' is `equiv.` (with a dot).

Also, the ACS page [Standard Abbreviations and Acronyms](http://pubs.acs.org/paragonplus/submission/joceah/joceah_abbreviations.pdf), shows equation abbreviated to `eq` and equivalent as `equiv`.

However, some journals, such as the Journal of Biological Chemistry page [Table I: Abbreviations of units of measurement and of physical and chemical quantities](http://www.jbc.org/site/misc/itoa.TI.xhtml) state that the abbreviation of equivalent is as you used, `eq`, so if you are intending to publishing, just be aware of what the journal expects in terms of abbreviations.